# npm install formidable error in installation

Tags: node.js

Hi I am following the book node beginner at nodebeginner.org and writing the file upload code. Everything worked fine but when i am trying to install the formidable package, it gives the following error:

```
    naphstor@ubuntu:~/node$ npm install formidable

    node.js:201
            throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
                  ^
    Error: No such module
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/output.js:8:21)
        at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
        at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
        at require (module.js:368:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/log.js:21:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
```

I have no idea about this and tried to search a lot but no help. i even tried using

```
    npm install https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable.git
```

but i get the same error. any help???

Comment: That's a weird one. Is your node/npm installation up to date?

Comment: I checked my npm installation, its proper. Anyways after some search i found out that npm actually does nothing but clones the library into its libraries folder which are then available for public use. So I manually downloaded the library in my working folder and imported it into my program and it worked fine.

Comment: Yep, that will work for simple libraries like formidable. You'll definitely want to get npm working though, otherwise installing things with lots of dependencies is annoying. npm also helps lock down  package versions.

Comment: @casperOne Why is this question considered off-topic?